# Links are not working when using query params in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Im using React Router AddOn of react.js and i have folowing 4 links

```
 <li><Link to="/configurations?configName=Project Status">Project Status</Link></li>
 <li><Link to="/configurations?configName=Invoice Status">Invoice Status</Link></li>
 <li><Link to="/configurations?configName=Project Classification">Project Classification</Link></li>
 <li><Link to="/configurations?configName=Notes">Notes</Link></li>
```

These link are not working dont redirect to corresponding page when i click on links and pass query `"configName"`.
but these links are working when i direct enter url in browser.

im using React Router "https://github.com/reactjs/react-router"

Answer (score 2):

It appears you haven't set up your query params properly as per react-router's example.

Try something like:

```
<li><Link to={{ pathname: '/configurations', query: { configName: 'projectStatus' } }} activeClassName="active">Project Status</Link></li>
```

For more information, view this example: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/query-params/app.js

Comment: its not working brother. its just changing URL in browser but page is not refreshing with i click on link.

Comment: currently as in 2018 it's search (string) instead of query, example search: "?sort=name"